# Is there a shortcut to switch between code panels in Spyder 5.2.1?

Tags: ipython, spyder

I'm currently new to Spyder and I'm trying to get a feel for the shortcuts.

I have seen that you can actually create multiple code panes using split vertical/horizontal (in order to work on multiple code files), however I didn't find any shortcut to switch between the multiple code panels I had.

So, is there any shortcut to move my text cursor from A panel to B panel ?

[image: A and B code panels]

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no keyboard shortcut for that, sorry.